# Duplicate WP Migration affecting site on separate domain?

Tags: sql, wp-config, site-url

I recently tried to back up my WP site to another (completely separate) web server. I ftp'd from Server 1, uploaded to Server 2, exported my SQL table from Server 1, imported to Server 2, and edited the wp_config.php on **Server 2** to reflect the new site:

> ## Database Configuration
>
> define( 'DB_NAME', 'Server2Name' );
>
> define( 'DB_USER', 'Server2Name' );
>
> define( 'DB_PASSWORD', 'Server2Pass' );
>
> define( 'DB_HOST', 'Server2Address' );
>
> define( 'DB_HOST_SLAVE', 'Server2Address' );
>
> define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8mb4');
>
> define('DB_COLLATE', 'utf8_unicode_ci');
>
> $table_prefix = 'Server2TableName';

I also commented out a couple lines that mentioned Server 1, and uploaded it. It showed **Error Establishing a Database Connection**, but after adding `define( 'WP_ALLOW_REPAIR', true );`, I was able to reach the repair page.

Here's my issue: When Server 2 has the original `wp_config.php` file, it redirects to the site at Server 1. When edited, Server 2 returns **Error Establishing a Database Connection**, and *so does Server 1*. Even if I use the URL for Server 1 without making any edits on Server 1, changing the config file on Server 2 makes Server 1 reply **Error Establishing a Database Connection**.

I want to run the repair on Server 2 to fix it's settings, but since changes on Server 2 are (somehow??) preventing Server 1 from showing, I don't want to run anything without really messing things up.

I'd love to be able to have two separate, working copies.

Comment: Did you check the URLs in the wp_options table? They should be set to the proper URL for the site.

Comment: I used a separate machine to try to reach the site at Server 1 when Server 2 was throwing the error, and both were down.